# Robotuim setDatePicker() picking current day's date only

Tags: robotium, android-testing

This is my code;

```
solo.clickOnEditText(0);
solo.setDatePicker(null, 2014, 8, 8);
solo.clickOnText("Done");
```

No matter what parameters I give, the date picker keeps returning the current days date. Does anybody have any idea how I can go about fixing this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should not pass null (number or object)

```
solo.setDatePicker(0, 2014, 8, 8); // the first param is an index
```

or first get DatePicker object:

```
DatePicker datePicker = solo.getView(DatePicker.class, 0); // the second param is an index
```

or by id:

```
DatePicker datePicker = solo.getView(String/int id)
```

then set date for the picker:

```
solo.setDatePicker(datePicker, 2014, 8, 8);
```

Comment: Hi. I tried everything you have suggested before but it still didn't work. I remember when I used a DatePicker object the calender just kept advancing and I had to terminate the test when it went passed the year 2021. When I test the date field manually it works well so I dont understand why it wont work with robotium. There are other parts in the test where this implementation works so I am a bit confussed.